# webpack-dev-server not working Cannot find module '../lib/polyfills'

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I moved my project to another computer, ran npm install. Project works fine except webpack-dev-server, it throws error

```
module.js:544
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module '../lib/polyfills'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:542:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:472:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:585:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/project/node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server:6:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:641:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:652:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:560:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:503:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:495:3)
```

What is it missing ?

Comment: can you share your `webpack.config.js` file?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had this exact issue and fixed it doing the following.

Running `webpack-dev-server` gave the error you pasted.

I thought it may have been a configuration issue, so I tried `node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server` to fix the configuration via the CLI.

Doing this, I was given the same error.

The file inside of `.bin` existed but something was clearly wrong.  I suspect it's because I seeded this project by copying from another one and perhaps references normally set as part of `npm install` weren't set on the copy, so they were still pointing to the source of my copy.

Regardless, run `npm install --save-dev webpack-dev-server` again and try.  Fixed my issue both in running `webpack-dev-server` and the CLI even though they were already installed.  Perhaps just installed improperly.

Comment: Also, if you get `cannot find ../package.json` after doing this -- give up.  Delete node modules and `npm install` all over again.  Lesson learned:  don't copy `node_modules` from project to project.

Comment: removing /webpack-dev-server in /node_modules/ and installing to again helped

Answer (score 44):

The fix: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`

Because..... who knows why /shrug

Comment: using `rm -rf node_modules && npm install` gave me errors, so I deleted manually node_modules and `sudo npm install`

Comment: Yep. This is what fixed it for me.

Comment: 2nd time I checked this error on Stackoverflow :) ... and this answer solved it :)

Comment: for me this happened when I was `scp -r ./folder me@another-comuputer:folder`  (copy project folder to another computer) so yes YARN was acting as resolved but actually dependencies were unmet (or something) ...so yes only solution is restart the node_modules by `rm -rf node_modules` and reinstall again `npm install` ... So great advise this answer. Give @sarink a cookie !

Answer (score 0):

I bumped my webpack-dev-server version in `package.json` up one dot release and ran `yarn` and that fixed it.

For example in package.json:

```
   },
   "devDependencies": {
-    "webpack-dev-server": "2.11.2"
+    "webpack-dev-server": "2.11.3"
   }
 }
```

Then ran `yarn` and the problem was fixed.